# How to efficiently store small byte arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-efficient

By **small** byte arrays I mean arrays of bytes with length from 10 up to 30.

By **store** I mean storing them **in the RAM**, not serializing and persisting to the filesystem.

> System macOS 10.12.6, Oracle jdk1.8.0_141 64bit, JVM args -Xmx1g

*Example:*
Expected behavior for `new byte[200 * 1024 * 1024]` is ≈200mb of the heap space

```
public static final int TARGET_SIZE = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    byte[] arr = new byte[TARGET_SIZE];
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Array size: " + arr.length);
    System.out.println("HeapSize: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

[image: jvisualvm total heap usage heap for new byte[200 * 1024 * 1024]]
[image: jvisualvm memory sample new byte[200 * 1024 * 1024]]

## However for smaller arrays math is not so simple

```
public static final int TARGET_SIZE = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int oneArraySize = 20;
    final int numberOfArrays = TARGET_SIZE / oneArraySize;
    byte[][] arrays = new byte[numberOfArrays][];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrays; i++) {
        arrays[i] = new byte[oneArraySize];
    }
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Arrays size: " + arrays.length);
    System.out.println("HeapSize: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

[image: jvisualvm total heap usage heap for 10 * 1024 * 1024 of new byte[20]]
[image: jvisualvm memory sample for 10 * 1024 * 1024 of new byte[20]]

## And even worse

[image: jvisualvm total heap usage heap for 20 * 1024 * 1024 of new byte[10]]
[image: jvisualvm memory sample for 20 * 1024 * 1024 of new byte[10]]

## Question is

<s>From where this overhead is coming?</s> How to efficiently store and work with small byte arrays (chunks of data)?

### Update 1

for `new byte[200*1024*1024][1]`
it eats
[image: jvisualvm total heap usage heap for 200 * 1024 * 1024 of new byte[1]]
[image: jvisualvm memory sample for 200 * 1024 * 1024 of new byte[1]]

Basic math says that `new byte[1]` *weights* 24 bytes.

### Update 2

According to [What is the memory consumption of an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java) 
the minimum size of an object in Java is **16 bytes**. From my previous *"measurements"* 24 bytes -4 bytes for int length -1 actual byte of my data = 3 bytes of some <s>other garbage</s> padding.

Comment: *From where this overhead is coming?* The array objects themselves take up memory too. It's not only their contents. Even an empty array will take up memory.

Comment: array is an object, has more than Typex[ N ], has head, type declaration, vtable, GC information for block,  like all objects. With hard professional work is possible for example move to 'off-heap', where garbage collector not work, and everything is totally manual (get few millions bytes from OS and do what want). Many cache systems have off-heap buffors. Numeric systems? Is not know to me, theoretically possible

Comment: Every array has [*the `public final` field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. `length` may be positive or zero*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7). Every array has a minimum overhead of 4-bytes (**plus** whatever overhead it inherits from `java.lang.Object`). That's a minimum 40% penalty (per array) for arrays of 10 bytes. What **exactly** are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am trying to implement my own "compressed strings" for my use case (external file sorting), but I noticed horrible memory inefficiency while working with small data chunks.

Comment: Use a sliding window. You might also take a look at `ByteBuffer`, even more specifically at [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318341/why-doesnt-java-have-true-multidimensional-arrays. Also you don't say what you're using to profile.

Comment: is it me or something i've missed? where are the small arrays? all i can see is HUGE arrays ?!

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer to the question in the title: Hide it behind an interface. `interface Data { byte get(int x, int y); void set(int x, int y, byte b)`. You can then store everything in a single array. If it is more convenient, you can also return "slices" of this large array in form of a `ByteBuffer` (using the `ByteBuffer#slice` method).

Comment: @Marco13 to be honest, I can't believe I did not include this suggestion in my answer (I actually wanted to start with this, but got carried away a bit with details... ) do you mind if I add it a a suggestion?

Comment: @Eugene Feel free to add whatever you want. I could also extend the comment to be an answer (with some implementation- and usage sketches, and maybe some JOL tests as well). This answer would then focus on "pragmatically" *answering* the title question, while your answer details the *reasons* for the observed behavior.

Comment: @Marco13  sounds much better! Plz do so

Comment: @Eugene Added. I always have to restrain myself in cases like these, from elaborating all the implementation options and pros/cons of each approach ... However, the key point probably is that the overhead can (only?) be avoided when using a (hidden) 1D array for the storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answer by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840143/3182664) explains the reason of why you are observing such an increase in memory consumption for a large number of arrays. The question in the title, *"How to efficiently store small byte arrays in Java?"*, may then be answered with: Not at all. <sup>1</sup>

However, there probably are ways to achieve your goals. As usual, the "best" solution here will depend on how this data is going to be *used*. A very pragmatic approach would be: Define an `interface` for your data structure.

In the simplest case, this interface could just be

```
interface ByteArray2D 
{
    int getNumRows();
    int getNumColumns();
    byte get(int r, int c);
    void set(int r, int c, byte b);
}
```

Offering a basic abstraction of a "2D byte array". Depending on the application case, it may be beneficial to offer additional methods here. The patterns that could be employed here are frequently relevant for *Matrix libraries*, which handle "2D matrices" (usually of `float` values), and they often offer methods like these:

```
interface Matrix {
    Vector getRow(int row);
    Vector getColumn(int column);
    ...
}
```

However, when the main purpose here is to handle a set of `byte[]` arrays, methods for accessing *each array* (that is, each row of the 2D array) could be sufficient:

```
ByteBuffer getRow(int row);
```

---

Given this interface, it is simple to create different implementations. For example, you could create a simple implementation that just stores a 2D `byte[][]` array internally:

```
class SimpleByteArray2D implements ByteArray2D 
{
    private final byte array[][];
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could create an implementation that stores a **1D** `byte[]` array, or analogously, a `ByteBuffer` internally:

```
class CompactByteArray2D implements ByteArray2D
{
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;
    ...
}
```

This implementation then just has to compute the (1D) index when calling one of the methods for accessing a certain row/column of the 2D array.

Below you will find a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows this interface and the two implementations, the basic usage of the interface, and that does a memory footprint analysis using JOL.

The output of this program is:

```
For 10 rows and 1000 columns:
Total size for SimpleByteArray2D : 10240
Total size for CompactByteArray2D: 10088

For 100 rows and 100 columns:
Total size for SimpleByteArray2D : 12440
Total size for CompactByteArray2D: 10088

For 1000 rows and 10 columns:
Total size for SimpleByteArray2D : 36040
Total size for CompactByteArray2D: 10088
```

Showing that

- the `SimpleByteArray2D` implementation that is based on a simple 2D `byte[][]` array requires more memory when the number of rows increases (even if the total size of the array remains constant)
- the memory consumption of the `CompactByteArray2D` is *independent* of the *structure* of the array

The whole program:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.openjdk.jol.info.GraphLayout;

public class EfficientByteArrayStorage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        showExampleUsage();
        anaylyzeMemoryFootprint();
    }

    private static void anaylyzeMemoryFootprint()
    {
        testMemoryFootprint(10, 1000);
        testMemoryFootprint(100, 100);
        testMemoryFootprint(1000, 10);
    }

    private static void testMemoryFootprint(int rows, int cols)
    {
        System.out.println("For " + rows + " rows and " + cols + " columns:");

        ByteArray2D b0 = new SimpleByteArray2D(rows, cols);
        GraphLayout g0 = GraphLayout.parseInstance(b0);
        System.out.println("Total size for SimpleByteArray2D : " + g0.totalSize());
        //System.out.println(g0.toFootprint());

        ByteArray2D b1 = new CompactByteArray2D(rows, cols);
        GraphLayout g1 = GraphLayout.parseInstance(b1);
        System.out.println("Total size for CompactByteArray2D: " + g1.totalSize());
        //System.out.println(g1.toFootprint());
    }

    // Shows an example of how to use the different implementations
    private static void showExampleUsage()
    {
        System.out.println("Using a SimpleByteArray2D");
        ByteArray2D b0 = new SimpleByteArray2D(10, 10);
        exampleUsage(b0);

        System.out.println("Using a CompactByteArray2D");
        ByteArray2D b1 = new CompactByteArray2D(10, 10);
        exampleUsage(b1);
    }

    private static void exampleUsage(ByteArray2D byteArray2D)
    {
        // Reading elements of the array
        System.out.println(byteArray2D.get(2, 4));

        // Writing elements of the array
        byteArray2D.set(2, 4, (byte)123);
        System.out.println(byteArray2D.get(2, 4));

        // Bulk access to rows
        ByteBuffer row = byteArray2D.getRow(2);
        for (int c = 0; c < row.capacity(); c++)
        {
            System.out.println(row.get(c));
        }

        // (Commented out for this MCVE: Writing one row to a file)
        /*/
        try (FileChannel fileChannel = 
            new FileOutputStream(new File("example.dat")).getChannel())
        {
            fileChannel.write(byteArray2D.getRow(2));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //*/
    }

}


interface ByteArray2D 
{
    int getNumRows();
    int getNumColumns();
    byte get(int r, int c);
    void set(int r, int c, byte b);

    // Bulk access to rows, for convenience and efficiency
    ByteBuffer getRow(int row);
}

class SimpleByteArray2D implements ByteArray2D 
{
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;
    private final byte array[][];

    public SimpleByteArray2D(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.array = new byte[rows][cols];
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumColumns()
    {
        return cols;
    }

    @Override
    public byte get(int r, int c)
    {
        return array[r][c];
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int r, int c, byte b)
    {
        array[r][c] = b;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer getRow(int row)
    {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(array[row]);
    }
}

class CompactByteArray2D implements ByteArray2D
{
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;

    public CompactByteArray2D(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(rows * cols);
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumColumns()
    {
        return cols;
    }

    @Override
    public byte get(int r, int c)
    {
        return buffer.get(r * cols + c);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int r, int c, byte b)
    {
        buffer.put(r * cols + c, b);
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer getRow(int row)
    {
        ByteBuffer r = buffer.slice();
        r.position(row * cols);
        r.limit(row * cols + cols);
        return r.slice();
    }
}
```

Again, this is mainly intended as a sketch, to show one possible approach. The details of the interface will depend on the intended application pattern.

---

<sup>1</sup> A side note:

The problem of the memory overhead is similar in other languages. For example, in C/C++, the structure that most closely resembles a "2D Java array" would be an array of manually allocated pointers:

```
char** array;
array = new (char*)[numRows];
array[0] = new char[numCols];
...
```

In this case, you also have an overhead that is proportional to the number of rows - namely, one (usually 4 byte) pointer for each row.

Answer (score 11):

OK, so if I understood correctly (please ask if not - will try to answer), there are a couple of things here. First is that you need the right tool for measurements and [JOL](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjMguOeoO3VAhWBVhQKHZ18AIcQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenjdk.java.net%2Fprojects%2Fcode-tools%2Fjol%2F&usg=AFQjCNGT9P70plOlG49Bj3gg1IOJMRdiWg) is the only one I trust.

Let' start simple:

```
byte[] two = new byte[1];
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(one).toFootprint());
```

This will show `24 bytes` (`12` for `mark` and `class` words - or Object headers + 4 bytes padding), `1 byte` for the actual value and `7 bytes for padding` (memory is 8 bytes aligned).

Taking this into consideration, this should be a predictable output:

```
byte[] eight = new byte[8];
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(eight).toFootprint()); // 24 bytes

byte[] nine = new byte[9];
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(nine).toFootprint()); // 32 bytes
```

Now let's move to two dimensional arrays:

```
byte[][] ninenine = new byte[9][9];    
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(ninenine).toFootprint()); // 344 bytes

System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(ninenine).toPrintable());
```

Since java does not have *true* two dimensional arrays; every nested array is itself an Object (`byte[]`) that has headers and content. Thus a single `byte[9]` has `32 bytes` (`12` headers + `4` padding) and `16 bytes` for content (`9 bytes` for *actual* content + `7 bytes` padding).

The `ninenine` object has `56` bytes total: `16` headers + `36` for keeping the references to the nine objects + `4 bytes` for padding.

---

Look at the produced sample here:

```
byte[][] left = new byte[10000][10];
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(left).toFootprint()); // 360016 bytes

byte[][] right = new byte[10][10000];
System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(right).toFootprint()); // 100216 bytes
```

That's a **260%** increase; so by simply changing to work the *other way around* you can save a lot of space.

But the deeper problem is that every single Object in Java has those headers, there are no *headerless* objects **yet**. They might appear and are called [Value Types](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html). May be when that is implemented - arrays of primitives at least would not have this overhead.

Comment: A side note: The "Value Types" are a very old proposal, and will likely come in one or the other form. Particularly, there have been *extensive* discussions related to a "Vector API" in Project Panama that employs these types. Although, unfortunately, I didn't manage to follow the discussions and proposals in depth recently, this *might* be related (see the messages around http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/panama-dev/2017-July/000622.html - there are many of them), at least when *assuming* that these small byte arrays are supposed to be "some sort of vector" in the end.