# Order of dimensions in a multidimensional array in Java affects memory usage

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, heap-memory

When I define a 4d array in Java like `var f = new float[1000][3][250][250];` it only occupies 797 MB on the heap memory. But when I define it like `var f = new float[1000][250][250][3];` it occupies 2273 MB on the heap (about 3 times bigger) according to the [IntelliJ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) profiler.

Can someone please explain the reason? Why does the arrangement of dimensions affect memory consumption this much?

Isn't it supposed to take around 750 MB anyway (1000×3×250×250×(4 Bytes of float) = 750)?

Comment: How do you know how many bytes the declaration actually consumes?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm using the IntelliJ Profiler.

Comment: Java does not have multi-dimensional arrays, just arrays of arrays (of arrays...) The first one has `1000*3*250`  arrays of 250 floats, roughly `1000*3*250` instances additionally to the `1000*3*250*250` floats; the second has `1000*250*250` arrays of 3 floats, roughly `1000*250*250` instances (more than previous) and `1000*250*250*3` floats (same as first) -- your calculation is missing the memory used for the array instances

Comment: `float[1][1000]` is one array containing another array with 1000 floats (2 instances + 1000 floats); `float[1000][1]` is one array containing 1000 arrays with 1 float each (1001 instances + 1000 floats)  [ignoring eventual memory alignment]

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of true multi-dimensional array in java, and that's where you are making the mistake.
in Java, new float[n][m] will be called as **array of arrays of type float**. In simple word, Java doesn't allocate the memory for multi-dimensional array like C or C++ does.

As Java follows OOP pattern and array is considered as an object too, if we have an array as `var arr = new float[2][3]`, we can change `arr[0] = new float[5]` later as well. In this case storing the the array data in continuous memory location, can really mess up. That's why Java store it in heap, where allocated memory can shrink or widened easily, in an array of arrays manner, where higher dimensions store the references for next lower dimension arrays.

Now, the size of the memory depends on the JVM and machine architecture I believe. How it store the array reference, the data and how it cache those data for multi-dimensional array, can make the difference.

here is a refference for more detailed information
[Why doesn't Java have true multidimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318341/why-doesnt-java-have-true-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: This is absolutely true, and is a big part of the answer, but I don't think it's a complete answer. After all, as you almost say, multi-dimensional arrays in C and C++ are *also* arrays of arrays! So the answer should explain why the "array of arrays" behavior *in Java* results in the difference that the OP is observing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the Java doesn't have true multi-dimensional arrays. An array of dimension 4 is an array of (arrays of (arrays of (arrays of float))) and therefore the size of the innermost arrays matters.

```
var f = new float[1000][3][250][250];
```

needs 1000*3*250 (i.e. 750_000) arrays of `float[250]`. Using[jol](https://github.com/openjdk/jol) to find calculate the size of `float[250]` gives 1016 bytes, it therefore needs 750_000*1016 bytes for the innermost arrays which is 750MB for the innermost arrays.

Adding the size of the intermediate arrays (750_000 intermediate arrays) gives you the 796MB that you observe.

```
var f = new float[1000][250][250][3];
```

needs 1000*250*250 (i.e. 62_500_000) arrays of `float[3]`. Using jol again to calculate the size of `float[3]` gives 32 bytes, it therefore needs 62_500_000*32 bytes for the innermost arrays which is 2000MB for the innermost arrays alone. Adding the size of the intermediate arrays (62_500_000 intermediate arrays) will give you the 2276MB that you observe.

Note that due to alignment restrictions and array overhead a `float[3]` needs 32 bytes or about 10 bytes per float element (!) whereas a `float[250]` needs 1016 bytes, just a little bit more than the 4 bytes that floats needs effectively.