# Efficiency: Objects inside arrays or arrays inside objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, micro-optimization

Given the same number of array/object layers, each index indicating the same things, what is the best order to nest the arrays and objects in?

I'm making a grid-based game, and I need to store several pieces of information about each square.  I know there's no getting around multiple levels of arrays/objects.  I've already got it working one way, so before I go changing a huge amount of code (I've got at least 5 functions with a heavy switch statement inside each one(to choose the layer we're working with), and maybe 10 others I'd also have to change, along with the initialization function), I'd like to know if this change actually lines up with best practices.

Currently, I've got it laid out like this: `Game.grid.map[x][y][layer][direction]`, so a map with a regular 2D array, and each element is an object, containing the properties of "V","S","M", and "G", each of those containing an array. (Metal, Silicon, Gate, and Via)

I was considering switching to `Game.grid.map[layer][x][y][direction]`  I would have to change a little bit of the structure (such as where I have `var base = this.map[x][y];` and then using `base[layer][dir]` But I could easily make this change and use variables baseM, baseG, and baseS.  It's just tedious to change it.  I would like to know if it would be more efficient to have 1 object with 5 large arrays rather than having a large 2D array with many very small objects.

I read somewhere that in pure arrays, it depends on how often the index changes on each level, with outer levels changing more slowly.  By this, it makes sense to change it.  I tend to deal with metal all at once, vias all at once, and Silicon and Gates together(ish).

Searching Google brought me to this QA: [Fastest way to read/store lots of multidimensional data? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966965/fastest-way-to-read-store-lots-of-multidimensional-data-java) but this only deals with pure arrays, not a mix of objects and arrays

===Edit===

1) So yeah, I missed that that QA I found was java instead of javaScript.

2) I modified their test a bit.

```
var arr = [];
for (int x=0; x<100; x++){
    arr[x] = [];
    for (int y=0; y<100; y++){
        arr[x][y] = [];
        for (int z=0; z<100; z++){
             arr[x][y][z] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This took about 10 ms.  (measured by pasting the function into the console and subtracting that time stamp from the 'undefined' time stamp.)  Between making the top level an object and making the bottom level a bunch of objects, it was also 10ms.  Making all the levels objects took 9ms.  This surprised me.  But it also means Bergi was right.  It doesn't matter.  I was concerned about the sheer number of objects in existence, but if 10,000 new objects takes less than 10ms, my 400-object grid shouldn't ever be an issue.

So really the only change in efficiency to be found is in how long it takes you to read/write code labeled in each way.  And for me, it's definitely easier to avoid parallel arrays on this one.  (I didn't realize this question would be on micro-optimization.)  Thank you to all who answered.

Comment: I'd wait until you've implemented the most efficient high-level algorithms you can find before even thinking about this issue. Micro-optimizations like this are a waste of time until you're sure that poor algorithm choice(s) isn't the source of 90% of your performance issues.

Comment: Also property lookup in JavaScript is generally highly optimized in any case. It's a fundamental operation in all JavaScript code.

Comment: Also also nothing about low-level runtime efficiency in Java will have anything at all to do with JavaScript.

Comment: That last one is why this question had to be asked.  There's nothing about this stuff in JavaScript that I can find easily on Google.  The other QA's I found were people who didn't know how to write objects in the first place.

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array? If you're working with a grid you can use a one-dimensional array and just keep track of where the rows happen. That way you have a single index for each grid square, and the math to handle the addressing is not only simple but something that JavaScript handles very quickly.

Comment: Robusto: It's a readability thing.  In order to make any sense in my many, many functions, I'd have to add another function to return the index for a grid square.  Granted, I already have a separate function for finding adjacent squares, because that's used in two different functions.  If objects had turned out to actually be slower, I might use that technique to flatten the properties of each square (tops 18 elements per square).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read on [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) and [major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) of multi-dimensional array. In theory, you can get some speed from cache locality, which depends on how you are going to typically access the array.

In practise, and especially in an interpreted language like JS, it will hardly matter (and there's much else to optimise first). Go for what makes the most sense to you, and stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are you talking about?  As [@Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280434/43906) mentions, there is a *LOT* more to optimize before you head down this road.  Technically arrays can be slightly faster to access via index during iteration thank objects via properties, even then it depends on the JS engine's implementation, which can vary a lot in tight situations like arrays of arrays.

Also, depending on the shear number of objects, you could hit memory constraints.  In the end, test in the browsers you care most about supporting. that's all it can come down to.  Avoid loops across too many items at once (Once you exceed 10k or so it can hiccup, over a million and you can have issues).

Comment: What do you mean by "*arrays can be slightly faster to iterate*"? Than what? And no, this has nothing to do with whether the size is "pre-declared" or not.